# PHP Beginner - a running total

Tags: php

So i decided to try and pick up PHP and after completing some online courses etc i have the basics to an extent.

I have been trying to test my self by making a simple game.

In the game you bet an amount of credits and a random number between 1 and 100 is generated, if the number is above 60 you get double what you bet back, if below 60 you loose the amount you bet.

Im stuck creating a running total and would greatly appreciate any advice.

Code below (apologies for badly written code :P)

```
   <?php
$rand = rand(1,100);
$usrBet = $_POST['usrBet'];
$usrCredit = 1000;

if ($rand > 60) {
$usrCredit = ($usrCredit - $usrBet) + ($usrBet * 2);
echo "Your Bet : " ,$usrBet;
echo "<br>";
echo "The Banker Rolled : " ,$rand;
echo "<br>";
echo "You Win";
echo "<br>";
echo "Current Credits : " ,$usrCredit;
} else {
$usrCredit = $usrCredit - $usrBet;
echo "Your Bet : " ,$usrBet;
echo "<br>";
echo "Aww Snap! you loose!";
echo "<br>";
echo "The Banker Rolled : " ,$rand;
echo "<br>";
echo "Current Credits : " ,$usrCredit;
}

?>

    <form action="dicegame.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="Please Enter Your Bet" NAME = "usrBet" placeholder="Please Enter Your Bet">
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: edit. i want the user to start with 1000 credits, the maths works but each time you enter an amount it resets to 1000 credits, thankyou in advance

Comment: You'll need to use sessions for this. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php Alternativley you could pass the user's current credit level as a hidden input field in the form. This could be manipulated though by users.

Comment: thankyou for your advice. is assigning 1000 to $usrCredits at the start the wrong thing to do aswell?

Comment: sidenote: you don't have a closing `</form>` tag. If it's not part of your code, add it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Got the </form> later in code just missed it when copying code in, thankyou though :) any good Session tutorials i can follow to learn them? any particular suggestions?

Comment: It's correct in that it won't cause an error; but it will always have the user starting at 1000 because every time the script loads it says user has 1000 credits.

Comment: An alternative to sessions is writing the balance to a file. Unlikely to do that in a real life scenario, but as you are learning....

Comment: $_SESSION['userCredits'] = $usrCredits; , Would this be along the correct line?

Comment: That is the correct line. You will need session_start() as your first line and a way to allocate 1000 on the first go. Good luck

Comment: you're welcome Jack. Plus, make sure you check if the input is numeric, because right now... one can even enter "text" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add some features so u could search in this way. As said $_SESSION will solve the pbm.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    <!-- Some few lines of JS - to disable characters input -->
    function isNumberKey(evt)
    {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }    
</script>
   </head>
    <body>

   <!-- U'll to re-edit the target of the form + changed type to number for input -->
    <form action="7.php" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="usrBet"  value="Plz Enter Your Bet"
               placeholder="Plz Enter Your Bet" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

// Check if user entered a value
if (isset($_POST['usrBet']))
{
    if($_POST['usrBet'] == '')
    $usrBet = 0;
else
    $usrBet = $_POST['usrBet'];

$rand = rand(1,100);

if(!isset($_SESSION['usrCredit']))
        $_SESSION['usrCredit'] = 1000;
if($rand > 60)
{
    $_SESSION['usrCredit'] = ($_SESSION['usrCredit'] - $usrBet) + ($usrBet * 2);
    echo "Your Bet : " . $usrBet;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The Banker Rolled : " . $rand;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "You Won";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Current Credits : "  . $_SESSION['usrCredit'];
} 

else
{
    $_SESSION['usrCredit'] = $_SESSION['usrCredit'] - $usrBet;

    echo "Your Bet : " . $usrBet;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Aww Snap! you lost!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "The Banker Rolled : " . $rand;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Current Credits : " . $_SESSION['usrCredit'];
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use session for storing the data so that the score will not reset

For using session you have to start the session like this

```
session_start();
```

after that you have to check that if the value is assigned in the session if no it means the user has its first attempt so we will credit 1000 points at start in session like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userCredits'])){
  $_SESSION['userCredits'] = 1000;
}
```

and when user credits is updated we have to update it in session to like this

```
$_SESSION['userCredits'] = $usrCredit;
```

if user came first on the page we don't want to give the result first so check if the form is post at the starting of the condition like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['usrBet'])){
 // PHP CODE
}
```

after all this the final code will look like this

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['userCredits'])){
      $_SESSION['userCredits'] = 1000;
}


if(isset($_POST['usrBet'])){

    $rand = rand(1,100);
    $usrBet = $_POST['usrBet'];
    $usrCredit = $_SESSION['userCredits'];

    if ($rand > 60) {
        $usrCredit = ($usrCredit - $usrBet) + ($usrBet * 2);
        echo "Your Bet : " ,$usrBet;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "The Banker Rolled : " ,$rand;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "You Win";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Current Credits : " ,$usrCredit;
    } else {
        $usrCredit = $usrCredit - $usrBet;
        echo "Your Bet : " ,$usrBet;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Aww Snap! you loose!";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "The Banker Rolled : " ,$rand;
        echo "<br>";
       echo "Current Credits : " ,$usrCredit;
    }

    $_SESSION['userCredits'] = $usrCredit;

}

?>

<form action="dicegame.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE = "Text"  NAME = "usrBet" placeholder="Please Enter Your Bet">
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

You can add more condition to it. Hope this will help